# If A reduces to B and B reduces to C, does that mean A reduces to C?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

If A is in the class P, B is NP-complete, and C is not in the class NP. And A reduces to B and B reduces to C.
Which statements are true?

1. A is in the class NP.
2. A reduces to C.
3. If S is a candidate solution to an instance I for problem A, we can check in polynomial time if S is indeed a solution.
4. C is NP-hard.

I think 3 is correct because A is in class P, and 4 is correct because All NP-hard problems are not in NP. I am not sure about 1 and 2

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @Nathaniel Added what I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [polynomial-time many-one reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Many-one_reductions). I will denote $\leqslant_m^p$ these reductions.

1. $A\in \mathsf{NP}$ because $\mathsf{P}\subset \mathsf{NP}$. This result does not depend on $B$ and $C$;
2. $A\leqslant_m^p C$ because $\leqslant_m^p$ is a transitive relation (proof left to you);
3. This is correct, $A\in \mathsf{NP}$ (see first point);
4. $B$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete and $B\leqslant_m^p C$. Since $\leqslant_m^p$ is transitive and given the definition of hardness and completude, $C$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

All four statements are true.